# creating an remote desktop connection with python

Tags: python-3.x

currently working on a project where an rdp connection is automaticely created with python.
First of all I edit the default rdp with notepad to see what's inside and if it is possible to change it the way I like it. It worked fine.
Now I turned the rdp into a .txt file to open it with python. Afterwards I want to add for example username so when the rdp is opened the username is already inside it.
But when trying to append with " rdp.write(f'username:s:{benutzername[anzahl_benutzer]}')". Its not working the way I suppose, because it doesn't append the "username:s:", it appends chinese symbols..

Can anybody tell me why..?

#Methode zur Erstellung der Remoteverbindung
def create_rdp(pf, destpf, benutzername, kd_nr, d, ip_adresse):
try:
os.mkdir(f'{destpf}/{kd_nr}')
anzahl_benutzer = 0

```
    for benutzer in benutzername:
        shutil.copy(f'{pf}/{d}', f'{destpf}/{kd_nr}')
        rdp = open(f'{destpf}/{kd_nr}/{d}', 'a')
        rdp.write(f'username:s:{benutzername[anzahl_benutzer]}') #Username in RDP-Verbindung schreiben
        rdp.close()
        os.rename(f'{destpf}/{kd_nr}/{d}', f'{destpf}/{kd_nr}/{benutzername[anzahl_benutzer]}_Rollout.rdp')
        anzahl_benutzer += 1

except FileExistsError:
    print("Für diese Kdnr existiert bereits ein Ordner.")
```